# Generic function Question C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have a generic function and the following class hiearchy:

```
protected virtual void LoadFieldDataEditor <T1, T2> (T1 control, T2 objData, string strFieldName) where T1 : Control where T2 : BaseDataType
{
  //I will need to access field1. 
  //I don't know at compile time if this would be SomeType1 or 
 //SomeType2 but all of them inherit from BaseDataType. 

  //Is this possible using generics?
}

public abstract class BaseDataType {}

public class SomeType1 : BaseDataType
{
   string field1;
   string field2;
}

public class SomeType2 : BaseDataType
{
   string field3;
   string field4;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible if you have some concrete type which exposes field1.  In this case you have BaseDataType which can given a virtual property that is implemented in all base classes.

```
public abstract class BaseDataType {
  public abstract string Field1 { get; } 
}
```

This allows you to access the property within LoadFieldDataEditor

```
protected virtual void LoadFieldDataEditor <T1, T2> (T1 control, T2 objData, string strFieldName) where T1 : Control where T2 : BaseDataType
{
  string f1 = objData.Field;
}
```

Implementing the property in SomeType1 is straight forward.  Simply implement the property and return the underlying field.

```
public class SomeType1 : BaseDataType {
  public override string Field1 { get { return field1; } }
  // Rest of SomeType
}
```

The question though is what should SomeType2 return for Field1?   It's unclear by your question how this should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Unless "field1" is declared on BaseDataType, it will not be accessible without casting to SomeType1.

Answer (score 1):

No, but this isn't really an appropriate use of generic methods in the first place.  Just rewrite your method as:

`protected virtual void LoadFieldDataEditor(Control control, BaseDataType objData, string strFieldName)
{
    SomeType1 type1 = objData as SomeType1;
    if (type1 != null)
    {
         // use type1.field1 here!
    }`

}

Generic methods do nothing for you if you're constraining both types to two specific reference types.  You can just use the base class directly - it's simpler, easier to call, more understandable, and works better overall.